# How can I have multiple arbitrary types in a typeclass definiton in Isabelle?

Tags: typeclass, isabelle

So I want to define a typeclass that looks like

```
class action =
   fixes name :: "'a => 'b"
     and params :: "'a => 'p"
```

This is so that I can create instantiations of datatypes that look like, for example

```
datatype ('b, 'c, 'd) actionT1 = Act 'b 'c 'd
```

where I would have

```
name (Act n c d) = n
params (Act n c d) = (c,d)
```

So in this case, the type `'p` in the class would correspond to `'c \times 'd` and `'b` in the class would correspond to `'b` in the example action.

Now I can use the functions `name` and `params` inside various functions, for example:

```
fun equalParams :: "'a :: action => 'a => bool" where
"equalParams a b = (params a = params b)"
```

Unfortunately, I can't actually achieve this because Isabelle seems to only accept one arbitrary datatype. Furthermore, if I try to do the following:

```
instantiation (string, int, int) actionT1 :: action
begin
.
.
.
end
```

I get an error saying that Isabelle expected a type constructor, but `(` was found.
How can I achieve this functionality in Isabelle?

Comment: I already get an error in the class definition: «Multiple type variables in class specification» (this is a limit of Isabelle's type classes). Instead of a class, you could use a locale.

Comment: @MathiasFleury Thanks for the suggestion. How would I use a locale in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you want to work with type, you can also work with locales. This avoids some limitations of the Isabelle class system. In your case:

```
text ‹Create the locale and define equalParams within the body of the locale›
locale mylocale =
   fixes name :: "'a => 'b"
     and params :: "'a => 'p"
begin
fun equalParams :: "'a => 'a => bool" where
"equalParams a b = (params a = params b)"
end

datatype ('b, 'c, 'd) actionT1 = Act (name: 'b) (c: 'c) (d: 'd)

abbreviation params where
  ‹params a ≡ (c a, d a)›


text ‹Instantiate the locale with our parameters.›

text ‹First in a named interpretation:›
interpretation action: mylocale where name = name and params = params
  by unfold_locales

term action.equalParams



text ‹Second in a unnamed interpretation:›
interpretation mylocale where name = name and params = params
  by unfold_locales

term equalParams
```

For more details on locales, refer to the [documentation](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2021/doc/locales.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the response, may I know how I can use the locale like a type in a function outside of the local specification? For instance, `fun f :: "'a :: mylocale => 'b"` where `f` can now access the `equalParams` function from the locale to apply on any element of type 'a?

Comment: locales are not types (so you can have multiple instantiations of the same type). You have to re-enter the locale with `context mylocale begin ... end` to do so.

Comment: I see, could you please include an example of this in your answer so others (including myself) can learn about this too?

Comment: I added a link to the official documentation.